# Binding is not displaying the correct value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Basically, I am reading a value from an xml file and displaying that value in a text box. This text box is editable so the user can make changes to it and when the session ends that value gets stored back in the xml file.

I know that the values correctly get stored and loaded to the text box. But I'm baffled as to why I cannot see the bound value that should be displayed in the text box..

This is the text box:

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.myView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:test.myView"  
         xmlns:local="test.myControls;assembly=test.mycontrols">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel Margin="8">
        <TextBlock Text="Starting URL"/>
        <TextBox Margin="0,5" FontSize="12" Height="30" Width="360" Text="{Binding myValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkTextBox}" local:WaterMarkTextHelper.WatermarkText="ENTER Value" />
    </StackPanel>
```

This is the INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaiseChangeNotification(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

This is the property im binding to:

```
public string myValue
    {
        get { return _settings.myValue; }
        set { _settings.myValue= value;   }
    }
```

I think it maybe because the value of the text box to empty before the code reaches the part where the start url is set using data binding. Does there exist a validate command in wpf that forces it to view the most up to date value?

Comment: Is `myvalue` a public property, and is an instance of the class that own this property assigned to the `DataContext` of the TextBox (or the window that contains the TextBox)?

Comment: Did you properly set the DataContext for your window/control?

Comment: Are you implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: Yes myvalue is a public property that it is bound to (it is in the ViewModel it is connected to). Yes the DataContext is set otherwise i wouldnt be able to get the value and store it in the xml file right? No i did not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, do i have to implement it? Or is there an alternative? Thanks

Comment: Post the relevant code. Otherwise it's all speculations.

Comment: I've updated the code - is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to know the exact problem, but there are a few things to check when this sort of things happen.

1. Check your `Output` window in Visual Studio. This will give you any binding errors. This will help solve some of the following problems:

   - Not having your property set to `public`
   - Typo with your property name
   - Not having the `DataContext` set
2. Make sure your `DataContext` implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface. This is required by the implementation of `WPF` to update the binding. You would do this like the following:

   ```
   public class YourDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private object _myvalue;

       public object myvalue
       {
           get
           {
               return _myvalue;
           }
           set
           {
               if (_myvalue == value)
                   return;

               _myvalue = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("myvalue");
           }
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
       {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, 
                               new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   You can also look up several strategies to simplify this, like INotifyPropertyChanged weaving or a `BaseViewModel` class.

### Edit

If `myvalue` is in your `ViewModel` that inherits from your `ViewModelBase` then all you need to do is change the implementation of your property to:

```
public string myValue
{
    get 
    {
        return _settings.myValue;
    }
    set 
    {
        if (_settings.myValue == value)
            return;

        _settings.myValue = value;
        RaiseChangeNotification("myValue");            
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, INotifyPropertyChanged is being implemented but am i missing something? Could i actually call the INotifyPropertyChange from another class? Other than the ViewModel?

Comment: @Manal Let me know if I am missing anything else.

Comment: Yes the view Model does inherit from ViewModelBase and I have added the RaiseChangeNotification but its displaying the value in the screen.. i think that it maybe because screen is generated and then the bound value is set in a different class so the RaiseChangeNotification is not being called.. what do you think?

Comment: @Manal If you add a breakpoint, do you see that it is not getting called? Are you not setting this specific property when you change it from a different class? If you set `_settings.myValue` directly, this code will not help.

Comment: yes the value is actually being set in a different 'Settings' class not in the ViewModel so the RaiseChangeNotification is not being called. You think i should move that code to the viewModel? Or is there a way to connect them? I wanted to keep the ViewModel separate from the Settings class..

Comment: @Manal I will let you design it, but that seems to be your problem. The `RaiseChangeNotification` needs to be called in order for the value to be updated on the UI. Just figure out the way it makes the most sense to you. You can look for guidance from ViewModel samples around the web if you are uncomfortable with the way you are doing it.

Comment: I moved the code to the ViewModel because that is the only place I could call the RaisedChangeNotification from and it started working again. But are there any alternatives to using RaisedChangeNotification? Thank you.

Comment: The other mechanism in WPF would be a [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx), but I don't think that makes sense in this case. If my answer solved your problem, could you mark it as accepted? Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious with this statement : 'yes the value is actually being set in a different 'Settings' class not in the ViewModel so the RaiseChangeNotification is not being called.' doesn't it mean that your textbox datacontext is bound to the settings class instead of viewmodel? I believe you should bind it to the viewmodel, that way the setting class can be separated from the viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

Try to add one dummy converter and see if binding is getting fired when you change value from UI textbox (Convert back method needs to be executed). Else take help of snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)  This will help you check status of binding.

And add RaiseNotification in setter if you want to update data from source to target.

```
public string myValue
    {
        get { return _settings.myValue; }
        set { _settings.myValue= value;  RaiseChangeNotification("myValue") }
    }
```

Comment: There are several ways to debug bindings http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/486#.UXFc16KSqOY. Dummy converter is not my preferred method, as if it doesn't to get called it does not give you any more information. I typically prefer using the TraceSources

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, this will come in handy!